# contraints in tableviewcell seem to be ignored

Tags: swift

I can't get these sliders to line up, Im not sure why.

[image: sliders on wrong side]

here's my storyboard ...that trailing constraint is clearly being ignored. What am I doing wrong?

[image: storyboard]

edit: for matt:

### I deleted all constraints

and control-dragged two of them, which should have been sufficient: the `trailing: 14` and the `center Y` (now on superview, the rhs being label was in error). there is no "remove at runtime" on any drawn constraints.

[image: View debugging showing issue flags]

the flags are visible but there's no indication of what they mean (the size inspector unhelpfully says only "has ambiguous constraint").

### edit #2

Based on input here and in swift discord, Here's an example of the view with changes applied:

[image: rebuilt]
[image: result]
and here is the relevant xml of that storyboard:

```
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" restorationIdentifier="RootAppCell" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="none" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="RootAppCell" id="PDl-Cx-SrR" customClass="RootAppCell" customModule="Assignment_5">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="343" height="44"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="PDl-Cx-SrR" id="EHS-uv-XgI" customClass="RootAppCell" customModule="Assignment_5">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="343" height="43.5"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <switch opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="750" verticalHuggingPriority="750" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" on="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="uDJ-B5-x3A">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="277" y="6" width="51" height="31"/>
                                            </switch>
                                            <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="App Name" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="fWL-xO-z8g">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="18" y="11" width="81" height="21"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstItem="fWL-xO-z8g" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="EHS-uv-XgI" secondAttribute="centerY" id="G84-Ys-Q8G"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="fWL-xO-z8g" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="EHS-uv-XgI" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" constant="3" id="JrD-j0-SxV"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="uDJ-B5-x3A" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="EHS-uv-XgI" secondAttribute="centerY" id="Q5Q-sy-Qh7"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="uDJ-B5-x3A" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="2" id="bMt-16-diy"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="uDJ-B5-x3A" firstAttribute="leading" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="fWL-xO-z8g" secondAttribute="trailing" id="he7-G6-aBc"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </tableViewCellContentView>
```

Comment: create a view in contectView of that cell , then put your label and switch in that view

Comment: Still having trouble with this? If you can recreate the issue in a very simple test project (e.g. nothing but a one-cell table view) I'll be happy to look at it for you.

Comment: its still not working matt. I am pretty much positive I can just delete the table and all sub components and rebuild everything and it will work. But I want to understand what is wrong so I dont have to restart .. like what if I waited to do constraints until after adding dozens of outlets ? the "delete and start again" tactic isnt a real answer so, I'd like to know what is wrong from where I am now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unclear on which constraints that are conflicting, take a look at the console output when you load the screen, you should be able to see something that looks similar to this

```
(
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6199cd0 UIButton:0x7fbbf90.width == 0 (active)>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6998ec0 H:|-(15)-[UILabel:0x6ce60] (active, names: '|':UIButton:0x7fbbf90 )>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6199000 H:[UILabel:0x6ce60]-(15)-| (active, names: '|':UIButton:0x7fbbf90 )>"
)
```

And to help even further, you can use this web page to paste that section and it will at least tell you which constraints that are conflicting in your code..

https://www.wtfautolayout.com/

Table view cells can be tricky since they will get additional constraints based on for instance what you have set as row height of the cell etc.

Hope this helps the debugging

Comment: thank you for the tip about wtflayout! There is nothing in the console

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried, and worked well for me:

[image]

Add Constraints:

1. Leading of the UILabel from superView is 15.
2. Center Y of UILabel is equal to superView's center Y.
3. Bottom of UIView (divider view) from superView is 0
4. Trailing of UIView (divider view) from superView is 0
5. Leading of UIView (divider view) from superView is 0
6. Horizontal space between UILabel and UISwitch is 5.
7. Center Y of UISwitch is equal to superView's center Y.
8. Trailing of the UISwitch from the superview is 10.

One more extra constraint needed for UIView (divider view) that is Height of the view is 1.

Here is the output:

[image]

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: 3,4,5 mention a divider view, which I dont see in the hierarchy ... unless that is the plainly labelled "view". If so, could you highlight it and add a screenshot? This may work (and working is good enough for me really) .. but do you know _why_ that is necessary ?

Comment: It's a 1 pixel height view. You can ignore this.

Comment: without the view, the only meaningful difference is #6. I revised my constraints to match (including #6) with and without that added view: in both cases it does not change the result.